# Range slider displayed on the main plot (and no secondary plot/axis) with Plotly

Tags: plotly, visualization, plotly-python, plotly.js

When using a [Plotly range slider](https://plotly.com/python/range-slider/), there are usually two plots : the normal plot on top + a small secondary plot on bottom where actually is the range slider:

[image]

**How to have a range-slider on the *main plot* instead, and no secondary plot on bottom?**

(if possible on Plotly JS, but if on Plotly Python, I'll be able to adapt)

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: @Hamzah Yes but when you do a zoom, it autozooms in the selected zone, which I don't want. I want to not change the zoom, but keep this display like my 2nd screenshot. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yes, I got it before your comment :)

Comment: You want to shade the left and right area and set the slider in the middle without the rangeslider below. Doing that without any zooming.

Comment: @Hamzah exactly!

Comment: How are you using the plot? The reason I ask is that the easiest method may be to put the plot in a container, then make the plot the size of the container, where overflow is hidden. I think that's going to be the easiest method to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Could be a good solution @Kat!